# Pattern matching with variadic templates and default argument

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

I'm trying to add a default "hidden" setting into a templated class:

```
template<bool DebugMode=false, typename... Args>
struct A
{
        A() {};
};

int main()
{
    A<double, double> a;
}
```

which fails when compile with g++ 8.3.1 and C++17:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<bool DebugMode, class ... Args> struct A’
note:  expected a constant of type ‘bool’, got ‘double’
```

Yet I don't understand why g++ can't do any pattern matching in template arguments. Will it be fixed a newer C++ version ?

Comment: I'm not aware of such proposals.

Comment: it's not broken. Rules should be universal. If your first parameter would be a type, how would compiler tell if you did skip one default parameter or if you did not?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie sure, but in this case the first parameter is NOT a type so it's not ambiguous for a compiler at all. I believe allowing this kind of flexibility would not harm "universability".

Comment: only if you use fundamental types. Such narrow use-case? Code `struct A {}; int main() { const int A = 3; std::array<int, A> arr = {}; }` is legal because scope context may define if identifier is a type-id or not. It only would lead to further confusion of people who read code. Nothing to do with compiler able or not able to translate it.  Source code IS a form documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's basically the same as with default function arguments: You can only omit parameters from the right. And I don't expect this to change, also because what you want to do can be achieved by adding a layer of indirection:

```
template<bool DebugMode=false>
struct Wrap {
    template <typename ...T> struct A {};
};

template <typename...T> using A = Wrap<>::A<T...>;

int main() {
    A<double, double> a;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
template <bool DebugMode=false,typename ...T>
struct A_impl {};

template <typename...T>
using A = A_impl<false,T...>;
```

Though here the default `false` cannot be really used, for the `using` you still have to specify it.